# Objective-c ARC is auto releasing my object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created a Global object when my App starts and set some global properties. 
I later reference one of these properties from a ViewController. Sometime's its fine other times the whole App crashes.

How can i tell ARC to not auto release my object?

```
#import "Global.h"
#import "GeneralHelper.h"

@implementation Global

@synthesize orangeClr;

Global* glob;

+(void) AppInit
{    
    glob = [[Global alloc] init];
    [glob setStyles];
}
-(void) setStyles
{
    orangeClr =  [GeneralHelper colorFromRGBA:255 :102 :0 :1];
}

+(Global*) get { return glob; }


@end
```

Comment: You are writing code that is so foreign to a ObjectiveC programmer as to be in another dimension, then you want help. What is this "Global *glob" doing floating inside your implementation? If you want a global, then make a static Glob *glob OUTSIDE your implementation. Have you read any iOS books or looked at any code?

Comment: Don't just say "it crashes", it is a useless statement.  Be specific.  What error messages?  Did you set an exception breakpoint so that Xcode will halt on errors instead of throwing them up to main() ?  ARC doesn't haphazardly release objects.  If it did, then the entire developer community would be in an outrage.

Comment: Please show the (relevant) contents of Global.h & GeneralHelper.h. Is the value returned by `get` invalid or the value of the `orangeClr` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the variable strong, you should also probable declare it static if the variable name is not used outside of the file.

```
__strong static Global* glob;
```

Comment: Strong is the default for any variable.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write singletons using single dispatch:

```
+(Global *)sharedManager {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Global *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Global alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you have singleton instance na, i.e.,

```
static Global* glob = nil;

+(Global*) SharedInstance
{   
    if (!glob)
    {
        glob = [[Global alloc] init];
        [glob setStyles];
    }
    return glob;
}
```

Now this makes sure that only one instance is there through out the **app**, and you can release  this when **app** is about to **terminate**. (It is one of the **design pattern**) You can refer to this class property from any **viewController**, and only for the first time it will **allocate** and **set style.** other times it will just use **previous reference**. Note it returns **Global reference**. Now your global class can provide many functionality and that functions will be in object level, not class level.

Eg:

```
- (void) someFunction;
```

can be called as

```
[[Global SharedInstance] someFunction];
```

And dont forget to include **Global.h** in other **viewControllers**

Comment: you shouldn't write singletons like this, use dispatch_once

Comment: its not that above written thing is wrong one or shouldnt be used .... has chance of others allocating and initializing... which is a rare case... can check this one  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

Comment: that example has much more code than yours, including overriding release and autorelease. dispatch_once is more correct, simpler to implement, and unless you need to support iOS pre 4.0 you should use dispatch_once